# Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 1 for 'Conv2D'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm using [Keras](https://keras.io/) with [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/) as backend , here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1373) 
import tensorflow as tf
tf.python.control_flow_ops = tf

import os
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.utils import np_utils

batch_size = 128
nb_classes = 10
nb_epoch = 12


img_rows, img_cols = 28, 28

nb_filters = 32

nb_pool = 2

nb_conv = 3


(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

print(X_train.shape[0])

X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)


X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.astype('float32')
X_train /= 255
X_test /= 255


print('X_train shape:', X_train.shape)
print(X_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(X_test.shape[0], 'test samples')


Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, nb_classes)
Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, nb_classes)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filters, nb_conv, nb_conv,
border_mode='valid',
input_shape=(1, img_rows, img_cols)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filters, nb_conv, nb_conv))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(nb_pool, nb_pool)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(nb_classes)) 
model.add(Activation('softmax')) 

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adadelta', metrics=["accuracy"])


model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=batch_size, nb_epoch=nb_epoch,
verbose=1, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))

score = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose=0)

print('Test score:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

and Trackback error:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
60000
('X_train shape:', (60000, 1, 28, 28))
(60000, 'train samples')
(10000, 'test samples')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mnist.py", line 154, in <module>
    input_shape=(1, img_rows, img_cols)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/models.py", line 276, in add
    layer.create_input_layer(batch_input_shape, input_dtype)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 370, in create_input_layer
    self(x)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 514, in __call__
    self.add_inbound_node(inbound_layers, node_indices, tensor_indices)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 572, in add_inbound_node
    Node.create_node(self, inbound_layers, node_indices, tensor_indices)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 149, in create_node
    output_tensors = to_list(outbound_layer.call(input_tensors[0], mask=input_masks[0]))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/layers/convolutional.py", line 466, in call
    filter_shape=self.W_shape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 1579, in conv2d
    x = tf.nn.conv2d(x, kernel, strides, padding=padding)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_nn_ops.py", line 396, in conv2d
    data_format=data_format, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 759, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2242, in create_op
    set_shapes_for_outputs(ret)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1617, in set_shapes_for_outputs
    shapes = shape_func(op)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1568, in call_with_requiring
    return call_cpp_shape_fn(op, require_shape_fn=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py", line 610, in call_cpp_shape_fn
    debug_python_shape_fn, require_shape_fn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py", line 675, in _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl
    raise ValueError(err.message)
ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 1 for 'Conv2D' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [?,1,28,28], [3,3,28,32].
```

First I saw some answers that problem is with `Tensorflow` version so I upgrade `Tensorflow` to `0.12.0`, but still exist , is that problem with network or I missing something, what should `input_shape` looks like?

**Update**
Here is `./keras/keras.json`:

```
{
    "image_dim_ordering": "tf", 
    "epsilon": 1e-07, 
    "floatx": "float32", 
    "backend": "tensorflow"
}
```

Comment: It may be problem with your keras input shape order setting. If you change `input_shape=(1, img_rows, img_cols)` to `input_shape=(img_rows, img_cols, 1)`, does it work?

Comment: @pyan , no it doesn't , `Exception: Error when checking model input: expected convolution2d_input_1 to have shape (None, 28, 28, 1) but got array with shape (60000, 1, 28, 28)`

Comment: Can you check what is the content in the file of `.keras/keras.json`, especially the value of "image_dim_ordering"

Comment: @Arman Ajoooo nice question! ^_^

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Your issue comes from the `image_ordering_dim` in `keras.json`.

From [Keras Image Processing doc](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/):

> dim_ordering: One of {"th", "tf"}. "tf" mode means that the images should have shape (samples, height, width, channels), "th" mode means that the images should have shape (samples, channels, height, width). It defaults to the image_dim_ordering value found in your Keras config file at ~/.keras/keras.json. If you never set it, then it will be "tf".

Keras maps the convolution operation to the chosen backend (theano or tensorflow). However, both backends have made different choices for the ordering of the dimensions. If your image batch is of N images of HxW size with C channels, theano uses the NCHW ordering while tensorflow uses the NHWC ordering.

Keras allows you to choose which ordering you prefer and will do the conversion to map to the backends behind. But if you choose `image_ordering_dim="th"` it expects Theano-style ordering (NCHW, the one you have in your code) and if `image_ordering_dim="tf"` it expects tensorflow-style ordering (NHWC).

Since your `image_ordering_dim` is set to `"tf"`, if you reshape your data to the tensorflow style it should work:

```
X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], img_cols, img_rows, 1)
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], img_cols, img_rows, 1)
```

and

```
input_shape=(img_cols, img_rows, 1)
```

Comment: Using this script: https://elitedatascience.com/keras-tutorial-deep-learning-in-python#step-1 

and making the 2 changes to lines 15,16&29 worked for me. Thank you!

Comment: Additional info: You can check which format is used (NHWC vs NCHW) at runtime using `if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':` (with `from keras import backend as K`).

Comment: I ise `if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    input_shape = (3, img_width, img_height)
else:
    input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)` and still get the error. Adding `padding="same"` helps in so far that my skript runs, but it seems to only mask rather than solve the issue... It is not clear to me what the actual problem is...

Answer (score 56):

FWIW, I got this error repeatedly with some values of strides or kernel_size but not all, with the backend and image_ordering already set as tensorflow's, and they all disappeared when I added `padding="same"`

Comment: This should be the answer

Comment: I had trouble with a multi-layer network for a week, where everything worked fine until I reached a certain number of layers and then I would get the dimension error. I tried all the other answers and everything I found on Google, but nothing helped. This fixed it, no idea why.

Comment: Thanks, I had three layers and the third conv2d gave me this error. This fixed it.

Comment: @user2939212 where exactly should I add the line `padding="same"`

Comment: @JeruLuke In the arguments list when you instantiate `Convolution2D`

Comment: @Jacquot Thanks for mentioning it. I also checked out the docs!

Comment: Using `padding="same"` does not solve problem, it just hides it. `same` padding works because it adds zero padding such that the conv or pool kernel achieves an integer number of strides over the input tensor. This is different, and produces different results, from `valid` padding. I too have not yet figured out how to get `valid` to work consistently.

Comment: Well this should be an answer!

Answer (score 19):

Just add this:

```
from keras import backend as K
K.set_image_dim_ordering('th')
```

Comment: and this is better than padding="same" cause not needed to be added to each layer

Comment: @user271077, re-read my answer ; this is not "better" or "worse", these are most definitely answers for different errors that give the same error message

Comment: AttributeError: module 'keras.backend' has no attribute 'set_image_dim_ordering'

Answer (score 13):

I am also having the same problem. However, each Conv3D layer, I am using, is reducing size of the input. So, including one parameter padding='same' during declaring the Conv2D/3D layer solved the problem. Here is the demo code

```
model.add(Conv3D(32,kernel_size=(3,3,3),activation='relu',padding='same'))
```

Reducing the size of the filter can also solve the problem.

Actually, Conv3D or Conv2D layer reduces the input data. But when your next layer does not recieve any input or input of size which is not appropriate for that layer, then this error occurs. By padding we are making the output of Conv3Dor2D remain same size of input so that next layer will get its desired input

Comment: Hey, I know it has been a while since you answered this, but can you explain a bit why this error occurs? Thanks!

Comment: Actually, Conv3D or Conv2D layer reduces the input data. But when your next layer does not recieve any input or input of size which is not appropriate for that layer, then this error occurs. By padding we are making the output of Conv3Dor2D remain same size of input so that next layer will get its desired input. Hope that helps. Let me know if you are happy with the answer. I will add this to my question then.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem, but it was solved by changing the conv2d function:

```
if K.image_data_format=='channels_first':
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 1,img_cols,img_rows)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], 1,img_cols,img_rows)
    input_shape = (1,img_cols,img_rows)
else:
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0],img_cols,img_rows,1)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0],img_cols,img_rows,1)
    input_shape = (img_cols,img_rows,1)
model.add(Convolution2D(32,(3, 3), input_shape = input_shape, activation="relu"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution can help is change:

```
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
```

to

```
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
```

After that, to run preprocess input data, I change:

```
X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 1, 28, 28)
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 1, 28, 28)
```

to

```
X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)
X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)
```

Finally, I change:

```
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation='relu',input_shape=(1,28,28))) 
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3,activation='relu'))
```

to

```
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu',input_shape=(28,28,1)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide size of filter using parenthesis like:

```
model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filters,( nb_conv, nb_conv) ,border_mode='valid',
input_shape=(1, img_rows, img_cols)))
```

It will work in my case and also change the X_train , X_test as this:

```
X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], img_cols, img_rows, 1)
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], img_cols, img_rows, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just had this problem. The bellow is the solution to work with the new API.

```
K.set_image_dim_ordering('tf') --> K.set_image_data_format('channels_last')
K.set_image_dim_ordering('th') --> K.set_image_data_format('channels_first')
K.image_dim_ordering() == 'tf' --> K.image_data_format() == 'channels_last'
K.image_dim_ordering() == 'th' --> K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first'
```

See more [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/12649)

Answer (score -1):

```
   %store -r le
   %store -r x_train 
   %store -r x_test 
   %store -r y_train 
   %store -r y_test 
   %store -r yy 
    import numpy as np
    import keras
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
    from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, GlobalAveragePooling2D
    from keras.optimizers import Adam
    from keras.utils import np_utils
    from sklearn import metrics
    num_rows = 40
    num_columns = 174
    num_channels = 1
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0],num_rows , num_columns, num_channels)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], num_rows, num_columns,num_channels )
num_labels = yy.shape[1]
filter_size = 2
# Construct model 
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=2, activation='relu',input_shape=( 
40,174,1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=2, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=2, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=2, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())

model.add(Dense(num_labels, activation='softmax'))
```