# keras Conv2d value error: Negative dimension size

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, tf.keras

New to keras, i am  dealing with a regression problem with Tensorflow as backend.

```
X1 = TrainingSet[:,0:603]
Y1 = TrainingSet[:,603:607]
###################################
#reshape Xtrain for CNN
X1 = X1.reshape(9999,3,201,1)

###################################
# create model
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1),
             activation='relu',
             input_shape=(3,201,1), data_format='channels_first'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), dim_ordering="tf",strides=(1, 1)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', data_format='channels_first'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), dim_ordering="tf",strides=(1, 1)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1000, activation="tanh", kernel_initializer="uniform"))
model.add(Dense(4, activation="relu", kernel_initializer="uniform"))

# Compile model
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mae'])

# Fit the model
history = model.fit(X1, Y1, validation_split=0.1, epochs=100, batch_size=100,  verbose=1)

# Calculate predictions
PredTestSet = model.predict(X1)
```

and i got the value error

```
ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 1 for 'conv2d_26/convolution' (op: 
'Conv2D') with input shapes: [?,201,1,3], [3,3,3,32].
```

I have already checked similar questions, for ex
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/7611

[Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 1 for 'Conv2D'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41651628/negative-dimension-size-caused-by-subtracting-3-from-1-for-conv2d)

However, their solutions do not work for me.

Comment: You are using a kernel size of 3 when your images width is 1. You have to use larger images or use convolutions which do not reduce the input size (at least the width)

Comment: Agreed, your training data has unusual dimensions. You can't do a 3x3 convolution with 1x1 strides if your data is 3x201. Reshape your training data or reduce the kernel size such as to 1x1.

Comment: @Guillem I have changed the form of my data set to 3*201 by setting X1 = X1.reshape(9999,3,201,1)?

Comment: @JamesKl Thx, but after changed kernel_size=(2, 2), it still doesn't work

Answer (score 5):

I was able to recreate your error

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
import numpy as np

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1),
             activation='relu',
             input_shape=(3,201,1), data_format='channels_first'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), dim_ordering="tf",strides=(1, 1)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', data_format='channels_first'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), dim_ordering="tf",strides=(1, 1)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1000, activation="tanh", kernel_initializer="uniform"))
model.add(Dense(4, activation="relu", kernel_initializer="uniform"))

model.summary()
```

Output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in _create_c_op(graph, node_def, inputs, control_inputs, op_def)
   1653   try:
-> 1654     c_op = pywrap_tf_session.TF_FinishOperation(op_desc)
   1655   except errors.InvalidArgumentError as e:

InvalidArgumentError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 1 for '{{node conv2d/Conv2D}} = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NCHW", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], explicit_paddings=[], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true](conv2d_input, conv2d/Conv2D/ReadVariableOp)' with input shapes: [?,3,201,1], [3,3,3,32].

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
14 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in _create_c_op(graph, node_def, inputs, control_inputs, op_def)
   1655   except errors.InvalidArgumentError as e:
   1656     # Convert to ValueError for backwards compatibility.
-> 1657     raise ValueError(str(e))
   1658 
   1659   return c_op

ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 1 for '{{node conv2d/Conv2D}} = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NCHW", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], explicit_paddings=[], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true](conv2d_input, conv2d/Conv2D/ReadVariableOp)' with input shapes: [?,3,201,1], [3,3,3,32].
```

**Solution:**

This issue can be fixed by including `padding='same'` to all `convolution` and `maxpooling` layers through which we can get same `dimensionality`( in default behavior 
i.e `padding = 'valid'`  there is a automatic dimensionality reduction occurs during convolution and maxpooling and will face negative dimensions issue).

While fixing above issue, came across with another issue is due `dim_ordering` in `MaxPooling` layer. This option was changed to `data_format' in Keras 2.

`dim_ordering='tf'` is equivalent to `data_format="channels_last"` accordingly i made changes to the network

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1),
             activation='relu',
             input_shape=(3,201,1), padding='same', data_format='channels_first'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding='same', data_format='channels_last',strides=(1, 1)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', data_format='channels_first'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding='same', data_format='channels_last',strides=(1, 1)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1000, activation="tanh", kernel_initializer="uniform"))
model.add(Dense(4, activation="relu", kernel_initializer="uniform"))

model.summary()
```

Output:

```
Model: "sequential_7"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_8 (Conv2D)            (None, 32, 201, 1)        896       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 32, 201, 1)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_9 (Conv2D)            (None, 32, 201, 1)        9248      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 32, 201, 1)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 6432)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 1000)              6433000   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 4)                 4004      
=================================================================
Total params: 6,447,148
Trainable params: 6,447,148
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```