# ValueError: One of the dimensions in the output is <= 0 due to downsampling in conv2d_64

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
def build_model(hp):
  model = keras.Sequential()
  model.add(layers.Conv2D(filters=hp.Int('conv_1_filter',min_value=32,max_value=128,step=16), ### filters are prob edge filter,vertical filter etc
                          kernel_size=hp.Choice('conv_1_filter',values=[3,5]),
                          activation='relu',
                          input_shape=(28,28,1),padding='valid',data_format='channels_first'))
  
  model.add(layers.Conv2D(filters=hp.Int('conv_2_filter',min_value=32,max_value=64,step=16),
                          kernel_size=hp.Choice('conv_2_filter',values=[3,5]),
                          activation='relu'))   
  # model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), dim_ordering="th"))
  model.add(layers.Flatten())
  model.add(layers.Dense(units=hp.Int('dense_1_units',min_value=32,max_value=128,step=16), activation='relu'))
  model.add(layers.Dense(10,activation='softmax'))
  model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(hp.Choice('learning rate',values=[1e-2,1e-3])),
              loss='Sparse_Categorical_Crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
  return model


tuner_search=keras_tuner.RandomSearch(
    build_model,
    objective='val_accuracy',
    max_trials=5)
```

> 

---

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
2     build_model,
3     objective='val_accuracy',
----> 4     max_trials=5)

7 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/layers/convolutional.py in compute_output_shape(self, input_shape)
303     except ValueError:
304       raise ValueError(
--> 305           f'One of the dimensions in the output is <= 0 '
306           f'due to downsampling in {self.name}. Consider '
307           f'increasing the input size. '

Value Error: One of the dimensions in the output is <= 0 due to downsampling in conv2d_64. Consider increasing the input size. Received input shape [None, 28, 28, 1] which would produce output shape with a zero or negative value in a dimension.

Comment: Why `data_format='channels_first'` ?

Comment: Hi @AnnaZhu, from your code it seems like the input shape is (28, 28, 1) where 1 is the number of channels and it means that data_format is `channels_last`. Also kindly try including `padding='same'` in Conv2D layer as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61837269/14290697). Thank you!